# Attendees not getting populated while importing an ics file generated dynamically to google calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I've created an ics file dynamically for my system. But when I try uploading it to google the attendees and the organizer is not populating correctly. Google takes the currently signed in user as the organizer and the attendees list is not shown at all. Rest of the part is showing correctly. I don't know if its because of the format of the ics file I'm uploading. I've given one of my ics file below. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
LOCATION:First meeting room's
DESCRIPTION:meeting on 2019-01-02 18:15:00 to 2019-01-02 19:15:00
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20190102T181500Z
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20190102T191500Z
SUMMARY:Meeting Invite from Raes  - test - on 02-01-2019 and 06:15 pm - 07:15 pm
URL;VALUE=URI:http://website.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=user1:MAILTO:user1@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=OPT-PARTICIPANT;CN=user2:MAILTO:user2@gmail.com
ORGANIZER;CN="Ryan leo":MAILTO:user2@mydomain.com
DTSTAMP:20190102T182226Z
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
UID:uniqueId
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

> NB: It's the attendees and the organizer which are not coming right. Rest is showing correctly.

Comment: From 2013, https://alex-holden.livejournal.com/261800.html.  2013 comment: "The consensus that I'm seeing is that because of the method uses to ensure the events stay in sync, it will not allow you to statically add attendees when importing a file, but you can programmatically add them with the API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert"  and according to google forums still the case: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/apps/_fGuUsUuHfk/STh7GEGuBAAJ